Llama3 via Ollama - Where can I find the default model system message?
I want to understand what the default parameters are. If I do not pass a system message what is the default one? etc..

From my understanding, if no custom SYSTEM message is set at runtime then no custom SYSTEM message would be included when the Model is run.
If the Model has a pre-built SYSTEM message this would be included during runtime while not including your additional custom SYSTEM message.
You can check to see if there is a built-in SYSTEM message within the Model by using ollama.
Run the below command:
ollama show Your_Model_Name --modelfile

Then you should see output similar to this:
# Modelfile generated by "ollama show"
# To build a new Modelfile based on this one, replace the FROM line with:
# FROM dollama3:latest

FROM C:\Users\User\.ollama\models\blobs\sha256-ea025c107c1c3e5a87380b25e205db3b19a4d2ed56f1954f531573a963621580
TEMPLATE """{{ if .System }}<|im_start|>system
{{ .System }}<|im_end|>
{{ end }}{{ if .Prompt }}<|im_start|>user
{{ .Prompt }}<|im_end|>
{{ end }}<|im_start|>assistant
{{ .Response }}<|im_end|>
"""
SYSTEM """You are Dave, a helpful AI assistant.
"""
PARAMETER stop "<|im_start|>"
PARAMETER stop "<|im_end|>"

I've not tested this fully but after playing around with these options it appears this is the expected behaviour. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong... Stackoverflow peeps do love correcting people 
